# local variable referenced before assignment in Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

What am I doing wrong?

```
from Tkinter import *

coordY = 400

win = Tk()

def key(event):
    if str(event.char) == 'w':
        coordY = coordY - 5
        print coordY

def callback(event):
    canvas.focus_set()


canvas = Canvas(win, width=800, height=450)
canvas.bind("<Key>", key)
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
canvas.pack()

photo = PhotoImage(file="image.gif")

canvas.create_image(400, coordY, image=photo)

naveY = 400

win.mainloop()
```

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'naveY' referenced before assignment

I want that when I press 'w' then the image moves up

Comment: Is that really the whole thing? There's no reference to `naveY` except the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing where your error comes from assuming theres more code, there could be a few different places. Does you error you get come from inside a class or function? if so try to set naveY as a global inside your function

```
global naveY
```

if your error traces to outside of a function or class is naveY defined before the line thats causing you the error? if so move your

```
naveY = 400
```

line accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where `naveY` (never mentioned anywhere in your code!) springs from, but here's a bug you have that could cause that exception (with a different variable name):

```
def key(event):
    if str(event.char) == 'w':
        coordY = coordY - 5
        print coordY
```

`coordY` is never defined (Python knows it's a local variable because you're assigning to it within the function), yet you're trying to subtract 5 from it -- what?!-)

I suspect this function is missing a first statement `global coordY` to let Python know that it's **not** a local variable -- and that your reported problem with the mysterious `naveY` is actually this very problem, and you just did some renaming in the code you're showing us, compared with the code you got that exception from:-)